Orientation and frame on a smooth curve
The standard defintition I use for orientation of a manifold $M$ is a choice of orientation at every point s.t. there is a local frame at each point compatible with it.
I think a manifold $M$ is orientable iff on each loop $\gamma:\mathbb S^1\to M$ there is a global frame of $\gamma ^* TM$ on $\mathbb S^1$, and iff for each frame of $\gamma ^* TM$ on a curve $C:[0,1]\to M$, the orientation of the frame at $1$ is uniquely determined by endpoints and orientation at $0$. Is there a nice way to prove this? How is this related to $\pi_1(M)$ and orientatation double cover?
The following are my attempts: I think for every curve $[0,1]\to M$ we can always find a frame, and if $M$ is oriented the frames at the endpoints must give the same orientation, and we can make them coincide by rotation at one endpoint. Conversely, if on every loop there is a continuous frame, and if $C,C'$ have same endpoints and two frames $F,F'$ on them coincides at $0$, then we can glue them together and compare them with a frame on the loop $C^{-1}C'$, and the determinant transition function must be nonvanishing everywhere so must have same sign. Now we can define the orientation at a point $x$ by extending any curve from a fixed base point to $x$ and extending a frame along that curve.
Is my proof correct? Is there a more concise proof?
